# Put the first value without id and class in a variable puppeteer js

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

The page contains the following code: `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">[{"text":"Must copy this","host":"http://google.com/"},{"text":"Must not copy this","host":"http://google.com/"}]</pre>`. How can i put the first text in a variable.I need to put exactly the value ​​of the first text field without [, {, "", etc
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a string that could be easily parsed into object:

```js
const objLiteral = JSON.parse('[{"text":"Must copy this","host":"http://google.com/"},{"text":"Must not copy this","host":"http://google.com/"}]');
console.log(objLiteral[0].text);
```

this will produce `Must copy this`.

How to get text from element has been explained elsewhere as well, read at least:

- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3051
- https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.4.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args

The whole example can look like this:

```js
const pre = await page.$('pre');
const elementText = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, pre);
const objLiteral = JSON.parse(elementText);
console.log(elementText[0].text);
```

Comment: but if the text itself changes when you open this page, will it work?

Comment: Depends on what changes. I suggest you experiment with it a little bit and see for yourself.